# Moving up to a certain cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a program that allows me to see what rooms in a college are free at a certain time in Microsoft excel.

The problem I am having is after I identify a empty class slot :

- how doIi code it to go back up into the names of all the class rooms (All names are at Row 2)
- and store the value of this.

I have tried offsetting but that wouldn't work for me.

I have added the [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcrhc.png) for further clarification

```
Public Sub EXq3()

Dim rnR1 As Range, roomNum As Integer

Const rooms = 13 ' Counter amount 
Set rgR1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
timeSolt = InputBox("What time")  ' asks user what time to enter

Cells.find(What:=timeSolt, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
          xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
         , SearchFormat:=False).Activate    ' search and find code

For counter = 1 To rooms
     If rgR1.Value = "" Then roomNum = rgR1.Offset(Range(2, rgR1.Value)) ' attempt at getting it to go to range 2
     rgR1.Activate
     Set rgR1 = rgR1.Offset(0, 1)
Next counter
MsgBox roomNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can change your code, try not to activate the cell in your VBA, just get the reference and do what you want to do.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use arrays and loops! It'll be far more readable and efficient! ;)

Comment: not sure what do you mean by `rgR1.Offset(Range(2, rgR1.Value))` ? what are you trying to achieve ? also in your post you mention "how do i code it to go back up into the names of all the class rooms (All names are on the range 2) " - where do you define and `Set Range2` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado i am trying to jump back up to row 2 as in the sample data above. I thought this would define that range but i must be wrong

Comment: @dave see my answer and code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably by "go to range 2" mean "go to row 2", am I right? If yes, this is your solution:

```
For counter = 1 To rooms
     If rgR1.Value = "" Then 
         roomNum =  Cells(2, rgR1.Column).Value
     End If 
     rgR1.Activate
     Set rgR1 = rgR1.Offset(0, 1)
Next counter
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so I assume that you have some time options in column A, and some values for Room 1 in column B, Room 2 in column C etc. I have refactored your code to get rid of moving active cell. It is finding some time in column A and checking if there are some empty cells in row with this time option, and returns messages with numbers of this rooms.

My test sheet:

[image: table]

Code:

```
Public Sub EXq3()

Dim rnR1 As Range, roomNum As String, rooms As Integer Dim timeSolt As String

rooms = 13 ' Counter amount timeSolt = InputBox("What time") ' asks user what time to enter

Set rnR1 = ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=timeSolt, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) ' search and find code

If rnR1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Something is wrong with Input." 
Else
    For col = 2 To rooms + 1
        If Cells(rnR1.Row, col).Value = "" Then
            roomNum = Cells(2, col).Value
            MsgBox roomNum
        End If
    Next col 
End If

End Sub
```

So, i. e. when you type 17 in pop-up window, the result would be "Room 4" and "Room 10".

Comment: yeah i mean go to the second row as in the sample data, but when i try running this code it keeps going to random lines after i run the counter on it and i have no idea why

Comment: It keeps going down to row with this code, i mean to go up to the second row where the rooms names are listed

Comment: Just seen there, yes that is exactly what i meant to try and do thank you so much. Is the messagebox after the first if for if someone types in a time outside of the acceptable ones ??

Comment: I missed some code formatting, see edit. Yes, the message ""Something is wrong with Input." pops up when there is no value like `timeSolt` in column A.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `Set rgR1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)` , you can just search for the `TimeSlot` entered at the `InputBox` throughout your worksheet.

Also, it's better to stay away from `Activate` and `ActiveCell` and instead use referenced `Range`s.

Since there is a possibility you have a few available room for a certain time, you need to store it as an array, and raise the index of rooms found on every match of `=""`.

There are more explanations inside the code comments below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub EXq3()

Dim rnR1 As Range, roomNum As Variant, TimeSlot
Dim FindRng As Range, i As Integer, Counter As Integer

Const rooms = 13 ' Counter amount
ReDim roomNum(1 To 1000) ' init Rooms avaialable array to a large size
i = 1 '<-- reset Rooms Array index

TimeSlot = InputBox("What time")  ' asks user what time to enter

Set FindRng = Cells.Find(What:=TimeSlot, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
                    , SearchFormat:=False)  ' search and find TimeSlot

If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then '<-- was able to find the timeslot in the worksheet
    For Counter = 1 To rooms
        If Cells(FindRng.Row, Counter + 1).Value = "" Then '<-- add 1 to counter since starting from Column B
            roomNum(i) = Cells(2, Counter + 1).Value '<-- save room number inside the array
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Counter

    ReDim Preserve roomNum(1 To i - 1) ' <-- resize array back to number of available rooms found

    ' loop through all available rooms in the array, and show a msgbox for each one
    For i = 1 To UBound(roomNum)
        MsgBox "Room number " & roomNum(i) & " is available at " & TimeSlot
    Next i
Else  '<-- could bot find the timeslot in the worksheet
    MsgBox "Couldn't find " & TimeSlot & " inside the worksheet!"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Public Sub EXq3()
    Dim rnR1 As Range
    Dim rooms As Integer
    Dim timeSolt As String, roomNum As String

    rooms = 13 ' Counter amount
    With ActiveSheet
        Do
            timeSolt = Application.InputBox("What time", "Input time", Type:=2)
            If timeSolt = CStr(False) Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if user cancels the dialogbox
            Set rnR1 = .Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Find(What:=timeSolt, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) ' search and find code
            If Not rnR1 Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            MsgBox timeSolt & " is not a vaild time" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "please try again"
        Loop

        With .Range(rnR1.Offset(, 1), .Cells(rnR1.Row, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft))
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Sorry! No rooms left for the input time"
            Else
                roomNum = .Parent.Cells(2, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1).Column)
                MsgBox "First room available at " & timeSolt & " is room " & roomNum
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```